# Grails referring js in https

Tags: javascript, grails, https

I have developed a Javascript library, which can be used in some of my other sites. It's a grails application. The grails application can be reach in HTTPS. However, there is a problem when referencing the JS file in HTTPS.

When including the JS library like:

```
https://foo.my.domain/appcontext/static/js/myjslib.js
```

Grails redirects this request to:

```
http://foo.my.domain/appcontext/static/bundle-bundle_application_defer.js
```

Please note the HTTPS -> HTTP which causes "unsecure" warnings, and the js lib is blocked in e.g. chrome and IE.

If I reference

```
https://foo.my.domain/appcontext/static/bundle-bundle_application_defer.js
```

directly, it works fine!

How can I force grails to NOT make this https -> http redirect, when referencing static content?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
<g:javascript src="myjslib.js" />.
```

Js file should be under web-app/js folder

Documentation is here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/javascript.html

Cheers

Comment: So how do you add it now to the view? Did you try <script src="https://foo.my.domain/appcontext/static/js/myjslib.js" type="javascript"/> ?

Comment: thats excatly what I do. As written in the question - when referring to the actual JS file Grails redirects with 302 to the bund-bundle_application_defer.js -- non https!

Comment: It works in grails 2.2 without problems. Which grails do you use? can you upload GSP file where you do this?

Comment: It might in 2.2 - i'm on 2.1.3. How did you test? You need to open your network monitor in the browser to actually see the 302 redirect and see that it switches to http. Sorry, my code isn't publicly available... But it has nothing to do with my code. Try creating a simple html file that includes a js file hosted by another grails app. Reference it by https - and you'll see the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem also. We are including JS & CSS from a legacy application that was causing problems in Chrome.

In our case, we have an nginx proxy that is doing the ssl encryption so configuring Spring / Acegi wasn't an option. The curl session below (edited to get rid of our server names / addresses) shows the redirect from https to http.

```
$ curl -v https://FOO.com/ess/js/framework/Widgets/Suggest.DropDown.js
* About to connect() to FOO.com port 443 (#0)
...
 GET /ess/js/framework/Widgets/Suggest.DropDown.js HTTP/1.1
...
 HTTP/1.1 302 Found
 Server: nginx/1.4.1
 Date: Fri, 31 May 2013 19:24:40 GMT
 Content-Length: 0
 Connection: keep-alive
 Location: http://FOO.com/ess/static/js/framework/Widgets/Suggest.DropDown.js
```

The solution I came up with was to exclude the legacy resources from the resources plugin using the excludes pattern in Config.groovy like this:

```
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']
grails.resources.adhoc.excludes = [ '/css/framework/**', '/js/framework/**' ]
```

Further documentation here: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/9.%20Configuration.html